# Combining two registers into one

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to take the result of a dword multiplication, in edx:eax, and combine them into one register.  I tried this:

```
    mov r15d, edx
    rol r15, 32
    mov r15d, eax
```

The most significant bits get shifted over just fine, but then the last line overwrites the entire register.  I thought mov r15d would only overwrite the lower half of r15.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're going to need to so an OR, not a MOV.

Comment: 32 bit operations automatically zero the top 32 bits. Note that since you are in 64 bit mode, you could just use the proper multiplication and not have to mess with combining stuff...

Comment: Replacing the third line with or r15, rax works.  Thank you!